# Placement of floating prepositional phrases

Tags: prepositions, word-order

Which of these sentences is better and why?

> 1. Nearly 1 million dollars was allocated by corporations for purchase of devices in 2013.
> 2. Nearly 1 million dollars was allocated for purchase of devices by corporations in 2013

Comment: Difficult to not be a little short with you here. Firstly, tell us what *you* think. Why might sentence 1 or sentence 2 be right/wrong? What is your suspicion? Before posting, try to check your verb form matches your subject, and as @snailplane pointed out, you are using articles correctly.

Comment: +1 @snailplane and also **dollars was?** - do you think it's okay? Or it should take *were*?

Comment: @MaulikV Measure expressions like this usually take notional agreement.  Although it's plural in form, we think of the quantity as singular.  "Two million dollars **is** a lot of money."

Comment: @snailplane I understand that - walking 5 miles **is** not a child's play (but then we have *walking* over there). In your example, you are talking about a lot of money that refers to the sum of two million. But then, here somehow it looks unnatural to me. Had it been *the fund/sum of nearly 1 mn dollars was..* it could have gone easy through my ears!

Comment: I removed *a* before the word *devices* to avoid further comments on that. I think the OP is interested in which sentence is better structured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two of them are... the same sentence, with different parts in different places. Another example:

> There's nothing wrong with what you've written as far as I can see.
>
> As far as I can see, there's nothing wrong with what you've written.

There is no set order of words in English for a sentence like this.

/*
As mentioned in the comments, 'devices' is plural, so replace 'a devices' with either *'the devices*', '*some devices*', or simply '*devices*'. These use the definite article, indefinite article, and 'no' article respectively.
*/

Edit:

Some other things raised. 'One million dollars' can be followed by both 'was' **and** 'were'. You can either refer to the 'one' set of a million dollars' or the one million 'dollars'. The 'one' takes was (as it's singular) and the 'dollars' take were, as there are multiple dollars here.

Comment: *a devices* removed. Thanks for pointing out though.

Answer (score 2):

When we have a sentence in the passive voice, then the **by + agent** *(to say who or what carries out the action)* is placed in the end of the sentence.

Therefore, the correct sentence is the second one.

> Nearly 1 million dollars was allocated for purchase of devices **by corporations in 2013**